# Regex Pattern to Isolate Multiple Double Quoted Terms

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, string, pattern, matcher

The pattern below allows me to isolate a single term that is enclosed in double quotes. However i'd like to be able to isolate multiple terms that are double quoted and separate them if possible.

```
pattern MyPattern = pattern.compile('("(.*)")');

Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher('asf "dfa, sfdsf  sdfasdf asfdasdf sdf asf , asdfs ,  asf sf" sf as"emily, md " dfa  ');
System.debug('THE STATEMENT MATCHES: ' + MyMatcher.find());
System.debug('THE MATCH FROM EXPRESSION: ' + MyMatcher.group());
```

The pattern above isolates the following string:

```
Isolated String: "dfa, sfdsf  sdfasdf asfdasdf sdf asf , asdfs ,  asf sf" sf as"emily, md "
```

However ideally i'd like to have the following isolated strings:

```
Match 1: "dfa, sfdsf  sdfasdf asfdasdf sdf asf , asdfs ,  asf sf"
Match 2: "emily, md "
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generate a `List<String>` to store results using a `while` loop. Also, change your pattern to `("[^"]*")`. The following worked for me in `Execute Anonymous`:

```
static final Pattern doubleQuoteWrapped = Pattern.compile('("[^"]*")');
static List<String> parse(String input)
{
    Matcher m = doubleQuoteWrapped.matcher(input);
    List<String> output = new List<String>();
    while (m.find()) output.add(m.group());
    return output;
}

String input = '"dfa, sfdsf  sdfasdf asfdasdf sdf asf , asdfs ,  asf sf" sf as"emily, md "';
system.debug(parse(input));
```

Output:

> [11]|DEBUG|("dfa, sfdsf  sdfasdf asfdasdf sdf asf , asdfs ,  asf sf", "emily, md ")